# Determine if today's date is between 2 database dates

Tags: php, date, mysqli

I know that this has been asked before, but I've tried the proposed solutions that I've found and nothing is working. So, here goes:

I have a mySQL database with 2 date fields sDate and eDate. These fields are of type "Date" and are input through an HTML form whose input is also of type "Date". What I'm trying to do is find out if today's date is between these 2 dates, inclusive.

```
$tdy = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));

foreach ( $conn->query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE sDate <= $tdy AND eDate >= $tdy") as $row ) {

do some stuff

}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in /home/peaceful/www/www/kokr/pages/cal.php:13 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/peaceful/www/www/kokr/pages/cal.php on line 13

Line 13 is the foreach. I've also tried several other ways of doing it, but they all throw errors. I would really like to stick with straight PHP on this. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you use PHP's DateTime instead of SQL functions?

Answer (score 1):

You need a *string* representation of that date that `$tdy` represents. Just use `DateTime::format()` to get a valid date string.

Assuming your date is in YYYY-MM-DD format:

```
$tdy = (new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago')))->format('Y-m-d');
```

I'll also mention, as pointed out in the comments, that you need to wrap your strings in quotes in your SQL:

```
$conn->query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE sDate <= '$tdy' AND eDate >= '$tdy'")
```

[Example](https://3v4l.org/Clv6I)

Comment: Technically you are correct. Which is the best kind of correct. :)

Comment: Thanks! that was the issue. I was comparing apples and oranges. Thanks for the quick response. I actually had the quotes, I forgot them when I typed it in...